# External dll SEHException ntdll crash

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, .net-3.5, ntdll

Patient is a C# application compiled using VS 2008. Application runs on multiple client computers using Windows 7 64bit and Windows 10 Pro 64. On June 11 they reported problems with application, probably after some windows update or another application installation, something changed in environment.

Trying go back to VS 2008 and debug situation leads us to System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException on line where external delphi library dll is called.

Since then we take multiple tests on client and own computers. But we were unable to create repetitive scenario, turns out sometimes it work sometimes not. 
We're looking for any hints since after week spend on problem we're not moving forward with this problem.

```
The name of the application causing the error: app_manageML.exe, 
version of application: 3.0.0.7, Timestamp: 0x58adba00
The name of the module causing the error: ntdll.dll, 
version: 10.0.17134.112, Timestamp: 0xcfe5bd82
Exception code: 0xc0000374
Error offset: 0x000d8879
The identifier of the process causing the error: 0x9b8
The time the application started causing the error: 0x01d40d5c465afc99
The path of the application causing the error: C:\e\app_manageML.exe
The path of the module causing the error: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report ID: f89ea556-3d9f-4032-8f53-9fa87143b700

Details:
System:
-Provider:
[ Name] Application Error

EventID 1000

[ Qualifiers]: 0
Level: 2
Task 100
Keywords 0x80000000000000
TimeCreated [ SystemTime] 2018-06-26T14:45:34.941965400Z
EventRecordID 1252
Channel Application
Computer WD-05.WARMETPL.local

Security:
EventData:
app_manageML.exe
3.0.0.7
58adba00
ntdll.dll
10.0.17134.112
cfe5bd82
c0000374
000d8879
9b8
01d40d5c465afc99
C:\e\app_manageML.exe
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report ID: f89ea556-3d9f-4032-8f53-9fa87143b700
```

Comment: This exception in unmanaged code suggests to me issue within your native Delphi.dll, may be it’s accessing some corrupt data in dB if so you could use sql profiler to get the query.. Here is the similar issue https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/187972/SEHException-while-calling-dll-function

Comment: But if you feel it was due to Windows updates you can always go back to that date and uninstall them..

Comment: `c0000374` this is `STATUS_HEAP_CORRUPTION`. very common and very hard to research error. and nothing related to *ntdll.dll*